# Suggestions with DevExpress GridView Custom Binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, devexpress

I am implementing custom paging and binding with a DevExpress MVCxGridView.

A link to the demo is here;

https://demos.devexpress.com/MVCxGridViewDemos/DataBinding/AdvancedCustomBinding

Now the data itself is coming from an api, so for example the GET end point for the data for example could be;

```
    public IHttpActionResult GetUsers(
        string username = null,
        string surname = null,
        string postcode = null,
        bool includearchived = false,
        int? pagesize = null,
        int? pageoffset = null)
    {
       var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<Users>();

        if(username != null)
             predicate = predicate.And(x => x.Username.Contains(username));

        if(surname != null)
             predicate = predicate.And(x => x.Surname.Contains(surname));

        if(postcode != null)
             predicate = predicate.And(x => x.Postcode.Contains(postcode));

        if (!includearchived)
            predicate = predicate.And(x => x.Archived == false);

        var results = _Service.GetUsers(predicate, pageoffset, pagesize);

        //filter out columns which are not needed
        var filtered = from x in results
                       select new
                       {
                           userid = x.ID,
                           date = x.Date,
                           username = x.Username
                           firstname = x.Firstname,
                           surname = x.Surname,
                           postcode = x.Postcode,
                           typeid = x.Type.ID,
                           usertype = x.Type.ID == 0 ? "Demo1" : "Demo2", 
                           archived = x.Archived
                       };

        return Ok(filtered);
    }
```

where pagesize and offset are passed across from the grid. So I can get a particular page of the data. The above is a crude example, but basically the idea is that the predicate is built up using the passed parameters, the return filter is done to whitle the fields returned from the EF down to only the required fields (and also set fields to lowercase).

(There is then an additional "/count" which takes the same params minus the pagsize and offset and returns the number of rows in the original query, so the Grid know the number of possible rows returned. An example method of this is)

```
    [Route("count")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetUsersCount(
        string username = null,
        string surname = null,
        string postcode = null,
        bool includearchived = false,
        int? pagesize = null,
        int? pageoffset = null)
    {
        var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<Users>();

        if(username != null)
             predicate = predicate.And(x => x.Username.Contains(username));

        if(surname != null)
             predicate = predicate.And(x => x.Surname.Contains(surname));

        if(postcode != null)
             predicate = predicate.And(x => x.Postcode.Contains(postcode));

        if (!includearchived)
            predicate = predicate.And(x => x.Archived == false);

        var results = _Service.GetUsers(predicate, pageoffset, pagesize);

        return Ok(results.Count);
    }
```

I now need to add in the column filters to the grid which i posing the issue that the grid shows more columns than there are filters on the end point. (Which can be seend in the demo link above with the searchable header text fields).

My issue is how to best handle these filter for evey possible column. The JSON returned from the WebApi the example may (more oftern than not will) contain additional fields that are not present in the filter parameters of the GET endpoint (so in the example above it ma contain fields like country, postcode etc).

So when the user effectively filters using the columns the WebApi GET cannot handle the search parameters and return accordingly return?

(As this is a generic solution which is db driven, and so realitically the api endpoints cannot be edited to handle all returned column filters, unless we can pass across some kind of text array that it can generically pase api side?)

Does anyone have any ideas on possible solutions or workarounds to this? I am sure this is something that may have been seen before at somepoint by someone.